# Key mapping in Evil-mode Emacs

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I am new to Emacs and have been using evil-mode. I have been having some trouble remapping some of the mappings that i had in vim. In vim it was easy to remap keys using the `map` function. I wanted to remap `cw` to `ciw` and `dw` to `diw`. But I dont have much understanding of elisp. So is there any plugin or function that allows easy mapping.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the bad news: out of the box this is currently not possible without influencing other operators as well. The reason is that `c` is an operator, so Emacs executes `evil-change` as soon as `c` is typed. Then Evil enters operator pending state and the following `w` (or `iw`) is read to figure out the correct motion.

The problem is that there is only one operator state for *all* operators, i.e. there is only one shared keymap. Thus, changing `w` to `iw` will change the behavior for *all* operators not only `c` or `d`.

First good news: if this is okay for you then you could simply do

```
(define-key evil-operator-state-map "w" "iw")
```

Now even better news. If you know the stuff above then it is relatively easy solve the problem using a little bit of Emacs lisp magic. The range that is passed to the operator is determined by the function `evil-operator-range`. The idea is to advice this function and temporarily change the keybindings if the current operator is `evil-change` or `evil-delete`. There are several candidate keymaps where you could place the new bindings but `evil-operator-state-local-map` is a reasonable choice.

```
(defun my/evil-motion-range (orig-fun &rest args)
  (if (not (memq this-command '(evil-delete evil-change)))
      (apply orig-fun args)
    (let* ((orig-keymap evil-operator-state-local-map)
           (evil-operator-state-local-map (copy-keymap orig-keymap)))
      (define-key evil-operator-state-local-map "w" "iw")
      (apply orig-fun args))))

(advice-add 'evil-operator-range :around #'my/evil-motion-range)
```

Actually, this technique would allow to implement operator specific bindings in a generic way.